# laravel unable to parse data

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I want to go to page edit from `PayAbleIndex` to `PayAbleEdit`.

On **laravel 5.4** i could use:

```
<a href="{{ route('payable.edit',$data->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></a>.
```

But currently I'm working on **laravel 5.7** and i copy same code but laravel couldn't get any data from it.

My blade.php

```
@foreach($purchase as $data)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $data->created_at }}</td>
      <td>@if($data->import == 'y')Yes @else No @endif</td>
      <td><a href="{{ route('payable.edit',1) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit {{ $data->id }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

my controller

```
public function edit(accountPayAble $accountPayAble)
{
    $pa = accountPayAble::where('purchases',$accountPayAble->id)->get();
    return view('pages.payAbleEdit',['pa' => $pa]);
}
```

My accountPayAble Primary key are not `ID` but `purchases`

my account payable model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class accountPayAble extends Model
{
  protected $table = "account_pay_ables";
  protected $primaryKey = 'purchases';
  public $timestamps =false;
  public function purchase(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\purchase','purchases');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide `accountPayAble` model file also in route how did you declare edit ?

Comment: i’ve edited my post

Comment: If you're passing `$data->id` in your blade `{{ route('payable.edit',$data->id) }}` then you need to pass that to your controller edit method as well

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I answered that already and can you please show me your edit route ?

Answer (score 0):

I think controller return array name should be purchase as below

```
public function edit(accountPayAble $accountPayAble)
{
    $pa = accountPayAble::where('purchases',$accountPayAble->id)->get();
    return view('pages.payAbleEdit',['purchase' => $pa]);
}
```

Check this and if it is not possible comment below.

Comment: still unable to get data... when i use `dd($accountBayAble->id)` it just return `null`

Comment: Try to change as $pa = accountPayAble::where('purchases',$accountPayAble->id)->all();

Comment: still not working, i think the problem not on eloquent but on parsing the data `$accountPayAble->` on laravel 5.4 i could use `$company = company::whereId($company->id)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: i've checked the difference  between 5.4 and 5.7 using `dd()`, on 5.4 on parameters there's data insde, but on 5.7 it's empty

Comment: You are correct problem is that statement in laravel 5.7. check this_____________________________
 $pa = accountPayAble->all()::where('purchases',$accountPayAble->id)->get();

Answer (score 0):

Here is how generally edit method works

If you're passing id in edit method parameter in blade like this

```
<a href="{{ route('payable.edit',1) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit {{ $data->id }}</a>
```

In this case route must have **/{id}**

```
// If you are using resource route then it will add /{id} in your edit parameter 
Route::resource('payable', 'AccountPayAble');

// If you've defined custom route then 
Route::get('/payable/edit/{id}','AccountPayAble@edit')->name('payable.edit');
```

In Your controller

```
// then you need to pass as well in your Controller method
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ap = AccountPayAble::find($id);
    // OR
    $ap = AccountPayAble::where('primary_key',$id)->first();
    return view('pages.payAbleEdit',compact('ap'));
}

// If you've primary key other than id then define key into your model
protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name';
```

I hope this helps.